# Is it possible for the Vb.Net compiler to switch on an "Unreachable code" warning?

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction

I've been mostly working with VB.Net for over a year and just noticed this

Am I going insane, or does VB.Net **NOT** have an "Unreachable code" warning?

The following compiles quite happily with nary a warning or error, even though there is a return between the two writeline calls.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
    Return
    Console.WriteLine("Unreachable code, will never run")
End Sub
```

Am I missing something? Is there some way to switch this on that I can't find.

If not, is there a good reason for its omission? (i.e. or am I right in thinking this is a woeful state of affairs)

Forgive the air of rant about this question, it's not a rant, I would like an answer.

Thanks

---

I've raised this on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com), as bug# 428529

**Update**

I received the following from the VB Teams program manager

> Thanks for taking the time to report
> this issue. The compiler has limited
> support for this scenario, and as you
> point out we don't have warnings for
> unreachable code. There are some
> scenarios that our flow analysis
> algorithm does handle, such as the
> following:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As Integer
    Return
    x = 4
End Sub
```

> In this case you'll get a warning that
> x has never been assigned. For the
> case you mentioned however we'll have
> to look at implementing that for a
> future release.

Comment: (flame)you're using VB so the compiler is mocking you(/flame) sorry.

Comment: Ian, if I could vote for a comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that it's an oversight in the compiler.  Flow control is a very difficult problem to get correct in any language, but especially in a language like VB which has so many different flow control mechanisms.  For instance,

- Exceptions
- Goto
- On Error (Resume, Goto, etc ...)
- Exit calls

If you feel strongly about this issue, **please** file a bug on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).  We do take bugs filed via Connect very seriously and do our best to fix as many as possible.

Comment: I know what your saying, but . . . C# has goto, allows returns in the middle of functions, has try / finally blocks . . . AND it can still spot unreachable code. I have opened a bug, thanks for the link

Comment: @Binary, VB's use of control flow though is **much** less restrictive than C#'s.  Much of it is hold over from VB6 days but these artifacts make it significantly harder to do proper code flow analysis.  Can you post the connect bug number here please?

Comment: Jared, anyone that's still using Goto, On error etc deserve what they get. We run everything with Option Strict On and expect "more" :) Bug number is 428529. Thanks mate

Comment: P.S. If it were up to me I'd spend 30 minutes every morning porting different projects to C# and be done with it . . . but it's not up to me

Comment: Select as correct answer purly for advice to raise this as a bug

Comment: Jared, I just read my last comment and thought it could be read as sounding a little sour, which wasn't my intention at all. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: @Binary no worries.  Thanks again for filing the bug!

Answer (score 1):

They mention this in the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210187/usage-statistics-c-versus-vb-net

See the last post.

I guess you could use FXCop to check your code instead or get a copy of Resharper from:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to address Jared's answer.

Most of the issues he brings up are not problematic for data flow analysis.

The one exception is "On Error / Resume". They mess up data flow analysis pretty bad.

However, it's a pretty simple problem to mitigate:

If more than one "On Error" statement is used in a method, or the "Resume next" statement is used, you can just turn off data flow analysis and report a generic warning. A good one might be something like "On Error / Resume are deprecated, use exceptions instead." :)

In the common case of one only "On Error" statement and no "resume" statement, you can pretty much do normal data flow analysis, and should get reasonable results from it.

The big problem is with the way the existing DFA code is implemented. It doesn't use a control flow graph, and so changing it ends up being really expensive. I think if you want to address these kinds of issues you really need  rip out the existing DFA code and replace it with something that uses a control flow graph.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you are correct that VB.NET does not give you a warning.  C# does though.