# Odd behaviour with generic Constraints on an Extension method

Tags: vb.net, generics, constraints

I must be doing something wrong here (because really, what are the chances of me tripping over another [bug in the Vb.net compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700916/vb-unreachable-code-error-warning)?)

I have a static generic function in .net 2.0 Vb code, I thought it was time to "upgrade" it to be an extension method, but the compiler complains with

> Extension method 'AddIfUnqiue' has
>   type constraints that can never be
>   satisfied.

Here's a trivial example that displays the same problem. The old static version (which works fine) followed by the extension method

```
Public Class MyStaticClass
    Public Shared Sub AddIfUnqiue(Of T, L As {List(Of T)})(ByVal this As L, ByVal item As T)
        If this.IndexOf(item) < 0 Then
            this.Add(item)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Module UtilityExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Sub AddIfUnqiue(Of T, L As {List(Of T)})(ByVal this As L, ByVal item As T)
    'ERROR: Extension method 'AddIfUnqiue' has type constraints that can never be satisfied'
        If this.IndexOf(item) < 0 Then
            this.Add(item)
        End If
    End Sub 
End Module
```

The equivalent code in C# has no problem, it's just a Vb issue.

```
public static void AddIfUnique<T, L>(this L myList, T item) where L : List<T>
{
    if (myList.IndexOf(item) < 0)
        myList.Add(item);
}
```

Has anyone any idea why this doesn't work?
It could well be my Vb constraints (I'm more comfortable with c#), but I can't see what I've done wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, the reason why it doesn't compile is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385206.aspx).

> *Because the method is an extension
>   method, the compiler must be able to
>   determine the data type or types that
>   the method extends based only on the
>   first parameter in the method
>   declaration.*

In your case, you simply need to change your code to this:

```
<Extension()> _
Sub AddIfUnique(Of T)(ByVal this As List(Of T), ByVal item As T)
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: You are indeed a Meta-Knight in shining armour. Thanks very much :)

Comment: How is C# able to do it? It has different syntax for extension methods, but wouldn't it have the same type inference requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a bug.

Funny thing, the same header works just fine not only in C# (as you already stated), but in VB as well - *if* you remove the <Extension> attribute.

So much about "extension methods are mere syntactic sugar."